# touchesMoved trying to resize a view with 2 fingers

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiview, resize, touchesmoved

When my touch points are top left and lower right, the following code works fine.

But if my fingers are in any other position, if I stop dragging my fingers while maintaining touch with the iPad screen, the view size pops back and forth from zero width/height to the desired width/height because the touch points seem to toggle back and forth.

How can I avoid this problem?

```
if([fingers count]==2)
    {
        touchPoint1 = [[fingers objectAtIndex:0] locationInView: self.view];
        touchPoint2 = [[fingers objectAtIndex:1] locationInView: self.view];
    }else{
        touchPoint1 = self.dragObject.frame.origin;
        touchPoint2 = [[fingers objectAtIndex:0] locationInView:self.view];
    }
        float rightXposition;
        float leftXposition;
        float topYposition;
        float bottomYposition;
        float wid;
        float hei;

        if(touchPoint1.x>touchPoint2.x)
        {
            leftXposition = touchPoint2.x;
            rightXposition = touchPoint1.x;
        }else{
            leftXposition = touchPoint1.x;
            rightXposition = touchPoint2.x;
        }
        if(touchPoint1.y>touchPoint2.y){
            topYposition = touchPoint2.y;
            bottomYposition = touchPoint1.y;
        }else{
            topYposition = touchPoint1.y;
            bottomYposition = touchPoint2.y;
        }
        wid = rightXposition - leftXposition;
        hei = bottomYposition - topYposition;
        newDragObjectFrame = CGRectMake(leftXposition,topYposition,wid,hei);
        if(newDragObjectFrame.size.height > 0 && newDragObjectFrame.size.width > 0 && self.touchesCount > 0)
         {
             self.dragObject.frame = newDragObjectFrame;
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out if i do this with the last if statement:

if(newDragObjectFrame.size.height > 20 && newDragObjectFrame.size.width > 20 && self.touchesCount > 0)

it works.

The problem was that as soon as my fingers rolled a few pixels into the positive zone, they would swap the touchPoints. Adding a buffer of 20 pixels prevents the problem.